# how to crop image dynamically in python3.i'm try to use python pip package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

(`area = (crop['x'], crop['y'], crop['x'] + crop['width'], crop['y'] +crop['height']`)

[[image: expected output]
[[image: but the output image is]]

Comment: first Image is  cropped one and my expected output but i got the second one is my output.pls suggest any solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install pillow - a python Imaging library.

Example

```
from PIL import Image 

im = Image.open("image.png") 

# Setting the points for cropped image 
box = (100, 100, 400, 400)
region = im.crop(box)
```

source: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html